# Finding the longest consecutive streak in a tibble column

Tags: r, tibble

I have the following tibble:

```
my_tbl <- tribble(
  ~year, ~event_id, ~winner_id,
  2011,      "A",     4322,
  2011,      "A",     9604,
  2011,      "A",     1180,
  2013,      "A",     4322,
  2013,      "A",     9604,
  2013,      "A",     1663,
  2014,      "A",     4322,
  2016,      "A",     5478,
  2017,      "A",     4322,
  2017,      "A",     1663,
  2011,      "B",     4322,
  2013,      "B",     7893,
  2013,      "B",     1188,
  2014,      "B",     7893,
  2016,      "B",     2365,
  2017,      "B",     3407,
  2011,      "C",     5556,
  2013,      "C",     5556,
  2014,      "C",     1238,
  2016,      "C",     2391,
  2017,      "C",     2391,
  2011,      "D",     4219,
  2013,      "D",     7623,
  2014,      "D",     8003,
  2016,      "D",     2851,
  2017,      "D",     0418
)
```

I would like to find out the most wins in a row by event id. The result I'm looking for would look like this:

```
results_summary_tbl <- tribble(
  ~event_id, ~most_wins_in_a_row, ~number_of_winners, ~winners,                              ~years,
   "A",       3,                  1,                   "4322",                               "4322 = (2011, 2013, 2014)",
   "C",       2,                  2,                   "5556 , 2391",                        "5556 = (2011, 2013), 2391 = (2015, 2016)",
   "B",       2,                  1,                   "7893",                               "7893 = (2013, 2014)",
   "D",       1,                  5,                   "4219 , 7623 , 8003 , 2851 , 0418",   "4219 = (2011), 7623 = (2013), 8003 = (2014), 2851 = (2016), 0418 = (2017)"
)
```

Please note that there are years missing because events did not take place during those years.

The following piece of code was provided to me but it does not work because of the missing years:

```
my_tbl %>% arrange(event_id, winner_id, year) %>%
  group_by(event_id, winner_id) %>%
  mutate(run = cumsum(year - lag(year, default = first(year)) > 1)) %>%
  count(event_id, winner_id, run) %>%
  group_by(event_id) %>%
  summarise(most_wins_in_a_row = max(n),
            number_of_winners = sum(n == most_wins_in_a_row),
            winners = paste0(winner_id[n == most_wins_in_a_row], collapse = ","))
```

Comment: Please note that for an event, there can be more than one winner per year.

Comment: What have you tried so far, even if it hasn't worked?

Comment: It's pretty difficult to read & make sense of code in comments. You can [edit] the question to include the code you've written, and you can format the code properly which I've done for you so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had problems with the missing years, so I had to use a base R approach with rle to solve it. For example, we take a subset where event_id=="A":

```
z = my_tbl[my_tbl$event_id =="A",]
```

To know all the years this event is held, and who won, I do:

```
table(z$year,z$winner_id)

       1180 1663 4322 5478 9604
  2011    1    0    1    0    1
  2013    0    1    1    0    1
  2014    0    0    1    0    0
  2016    0    0    0    1    0
  2017    0    1    1    0    0
```

This simplifies the problem to finding maximum consecutive 1s for each column. For this I use rle,

```
apply(table(z$year,z$winner_id),2,function(i){
           k=rle(i)
           max(k$lengths[k$values == 1])
         })
1180 1663 4322 5478 9604 
   1    1    3    1    2
```

Showing 4322 has the longest streak, for event_id == A subset. With this, it is easy to write the output you need into a data.frame. And the rest is to apply this function over all subsets of data:

```
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

findLongestStreak = function(z){
TAB=table(z$year,z$winner_id)
max_per_id = apply(TAB,2,function(i){
          k=rle(i)
          MAX = max(k$lengths[k$values == 1])
          YEARS = rownames(TAB)[which(rep(k$lengths==MAX,k$lengths) & i==1)[1:MAX]]
          data.frame(
            N=MAX,
            YEARS=paste(YEARS,collapse=","))
        })
max_per_id = do.call(rbind,max_per_id)
WINNERS = max_per_id$N == max(max_per_id$N)
data.frame(
  event_id = z$event_id[1],
  most_wins_in_a_row = max(max_per_id$N),
  number_of_winners = sum(WINNERS),
  winners=paste(rownames(max_per_id)[WINNERS],collapse=","),
  years=paste(max_per_id$YEARS[WINNERS],collapse=";"),
  stringsAsFactors=F
)
}

my_tbl %>% split(.$event_id) %>% map_dfr(findLongestStreak)
  event_id most_wins_in_a_row number_of_winners                 winners
1        A                  3                 1                    4322
2        B                  3                 1                    7893
3        C                  3                 2               2391,5556
4        D                  3                 5 418,2851,4219,7623,8003
                     years
1           2011,2013,2014
2                2013,2014
3      2016,2017;2011,2013
4 2017;2016;2011;2013;2014
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a way to add a column with the years where the wins have taken place in a row (see my results_summary_tbl )? Also, should I give up trying to find a solution using lag()?

Comment: hey years are not so easy. because if there are ties, for example if the maximum streak is 1, and for a individual, there are two such streaks, what do you do?

Comment: ok done, I got the years out.. so they are separated by ";" in the years columns and correspond to the order they appear in the winners column

Comment: When I run it, I get the folowing error:  Error in data.frame(event_id = z$event_id[1], most_wins_in_a_row = N,  : 
  object 'N' not found

Comment: yes. Bug. Thanks for the feedback. Fixed it... see if it works now? Sorry pulling out the years really consumed me =p

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH. I will now try to understand your solution which works as expected. I might post the same question to see if it's possible to get the same result by using only lag().

Comment: No worries.. I tried lag + dplyr too.. was killing me :)